# casting Enumeration to the List

Tags: java, casting

This seems really basic, but when we are casting `java.util.Enumeration` to a `java.util.List` like here:

```
// Enumeration getInitParameterNames()
java.util.List e2 =  (List) getServletConfig().getInitParameterNames();
```

are we doing "down casting" or "up casting"?

Also these two Interfaces doesn't have anything in common (except the fact that they are both inside `java.util`) (`public interface Enumeration<E>` and `public interface List<E>
extends Collection<E>`)

so why even we can cast them to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're neither "down casting" nor "up casting" (since neither is a subtype of the other).

If the result from `getServletConfig().getInitParameterNames()` is an object that implements `List` you may cast it as you've show in your code. Otherwise you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

It doesn't matter if the two interfaces have anything in common. An object can implement both interfaces:

```
class InitParameterNames implements Enumeration, List {
    ...
}
```

Comment: so what is the rule here for casting? How we can find out we can cast two obj to each other?

Comment: @Aaron The compiler is fine with casting an interface to another. Even if two interfaces `MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2` do not belong to the same inheritance hierarchy, a class `X` is free to implement both and then `X` becomes of type `MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2`.

Answer (score 1):

By doing a cast like this, the compiler thinks you are absolutely certain the two types you are casting are compatible. It won't complain.

The runtime will throw ClassCastException if the two types are actually incompatible. I think it will be the case in your scenario.

**EDIT:**

Compiler can sport certain types of cast, mainly the Java predefined types:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    List l = (List)map;
    Set s = (Set)map;
    Date d = (Date)map;
    IllegalArgumentException e = (IllegalArgumentException)map;
```

The above casts are all fine by the compiler, but will have ClassCastException.

However, if you try to cast:

```
Double dd = (Double)map;
```

It will be a compile error as the compiler knows what a Double is.